# Execute script after removepkg in Slackware

Tags: packages, slackware

I've created a slackware build script so I could build a specific package and then install it on a couple of servers running identical versions. I'm aware you could use `doinst.sh` to do things after the package was installed, but is there a similar script that's executed upon uninstall? For example, when the package is installed, in `doinst.sh` I have a couple of specific environment variables that append to `/etc/profile`. I'm wondering if it is possible to automatically remove them from `/etc/profile` if the package gets deleted (i.e. create a `douninst.sh` that would do that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slackware Linux doesn't have any provision for post package removal scripts. You may want to create a remove script and manually run it anytime you remove the package. It would be nice if there were built-in support for this though.

Comment: Yes, I've notice there isn't any other solution rather than just running the script myself. Hopefully they change that in 10 years from now. Thanks! :)